# How to insert more data when registering a user in Laravel Spark

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I'm using Laravel Spark for my latest app and need to insert a random code to a column in the table upon registration.

After A LOT of digging through the code I've found this block of code:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  RegisterRequest  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    Auth::login($user = Spark::interact(
        Register::class, [$request]
    ));

    event(new UserRegistered($user));

    return response()->json([
        'redirect' => $this->redirectPath()
    ]);
}
```

Which is found in `Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;`

Which I assume is where the code for inserting a user into the database is happening. But I cannot for the life of me work out how to populate a column called `confirmation_code` with something like `13sfet1201`.

I'm so stuck on this, so please offer any advice you can.

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: Does this help? https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization Is it possible to swap out the appropriate classes for your own which implement the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for looking @haakym I did originally look there but didn't fully understand if what I wanted would be handled via that, it looks like `UserRepository` in `Laravel\Spark\Repositories`is where the logic for inserting users is stored. I've just added my logic for the extra fields inside the already existing one and seems to work well :)

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, to get around this you can do the following:

There is a file located at `Laravel\Spark\Repositories` called `UserRepository.php`. This is where the logic to create new users is handled.

In this file you'll see the following block:

```
$user->forceFill([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'last_read_announcements_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::trialDays()),
])->save();
```

I modified it to suit what I needed, like so:

```
$user->forceFill([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'confirmation_code' => $data['confirmation_code'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'last_read_announcements_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::trialDays()),
])->save();
```

Works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way of doing this in Spark was to override the user creation method in SparkServiceProvider. Spark has some special built-in methods to allow this.

In app/Providers/SparkServiceProvider.php you can add something like this to the booted() method:

```
        Spark::createUsersWith(function ($request) {
            $user = Spark::user();

            // trim these form fields
            $fields = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'timezone', 'referral_code'];
            $data = array_map('trim', $request->only($fields)); 

            // now add user
            $user->forceFill([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'tzone' => $data['timezone'],
                'referred_by' => $data['referral_code'],
                'last_read_announcements_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::trialDays()),
            ])->save();

            // here you can queue notification email to user and 
            // all that post-registration stuff, or you could fire an event
            // and add listener to handle this

            return $user;
        });
```

You will probably also want to add custom validation for user data. Just add your rules to booted() method, the same way as in the previous snippet:

```
        Spark::validateUsersWith(function ($request) {
            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed', 
                'timezone' => 'required|timezone',
                'terms' => 'required|accepted',
                'referral_code' => 'alpha_num', 
            ];

            return $rules;
        });
```

Comment: Would this be affected by core file updates at all? I haven't touched Spark for a year now so can't remember how its set up haha.

Comment: No, all the changes go to app/Providers/SparkServiceProvider.php, which is yours to edit. Updates will not be affected with this at all... with a little of digging through the code you can override pretty much everything in Spark without ever needing to edit core files.

Comment: For me this only worked on initial registration, but when I go to edit the profile it doesn't update :(